# Objective c set value to a property if not null

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to set value to property if the value being passed exist.

One way is to use if else condition

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
               viewIdentifier:(int64_t)viewId
                    arguments:(id _Nullable)args
              binaryMessenger:(NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger>*)messenger {


        if ([args valueForKey:@"name"]) {
         config.name = [args valueForKey:@"name"];
       }
```

but I was thinking if there is cleaner way to doing it?

In javascript I could have simply done something like this

```
const a = args.name || null
```

Comment: `[args valueForKey:@"name"]` will return `nil` if there is no value for the key, so you can just say `config.name = [args valueForKey:@"name"]`, no need for the `if`

Comment: As a note, `id` isn't a great type to use for `args` - It is basically "Any object".  If `args` is a dictionary then use `NSDictionary`